# Javafx gui hides behind taskbar after screen switch

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx, taskbar

Whenever the GUI is being dragged to another (smaller) screen, the lower part of the GUI hides behind the taskbar. Any idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't this just standard behavior for any window in your OS, not just the window of the application you coded?  If not please provide screenshots of the difference of the behavior between your window and another OS window.